# LDAP in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, active-directory

In our current system, we query the LDAP using SQL Server 2008R2 but are moving to SQL Server 2012 where we have hit a snag. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707782.aspx one of the discontinued features of SQL Server 2012 is the AD helper service.

Does anyone know of a way to query the AD from SQL Server 2012?

Comment: You could e.g. use a web service and call it using SQL-CLR from your SQL Server code

Comment: I would think this is possible using SQLCLR directly, but I haven't tried it. That's where I would start, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to create a linked server to an LDAP database and query the LDAP database directly via the linked server.

There's information here on setting up the [linked server](http://sql.dzone.com/news/querying-active-directory-thro).

To test I setup the linked server based on [this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/).  Then I ran the following code and got back a recordset with various information in it (where bacon.lab is my AD domain).

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( 
  ADSI,  
  'SELECT displayName, telephoneNumber, mail, mobile, facsimileTelephoneNumber 
  FROM ''LDAP://bacon.lab''
  WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' 
  ') AS tblADSI
ORDER BY displayname
```

Comment: The problem isn't setting up a linked server but querying the LDAP which uses the Active Directory Helper Service

Comment: Setting up a linked server to AD on SQL 2012 I'm able to query active directory without issue via the linked server.  The AD Helper service is used when SQL Server needs to create objects in AD, not when it needs to query AD.

Comment: @user1207758: Those procedures have been removed in 2012. You will have to rewrite your code.

Comment: @mrdenny, were you trying this with SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012?  I can't get it to work, even after following the instruction you provided.

Comment: When I wrote that sample code my lab would have been SQL 2012 on Windows 2012.  Make sure that you change the domain name from bacon.lab to your domain name.